# Deploy Build of angular2 on server

Tags: angular

I have an web app built with angular2, after running i command `ng build` , dist folder gets created in my folder structure, now i want to publish this on server.

So i simply copy and paste `dist` folder there and running `index.html`

but it is showing error in developer console

```
Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'parentFolder/childFolder/dist'
```

Most probably error is in my base URL.

PS: I already set base href as `<base href="./">`

any idea ?

Comment: your publish which server apache ?? or tomcat ??

Comment: apche server i am using

Comment: can you refer my answer, below configuration

Comment: let me know if your struggle

Answer (score 0):

You need to Copy the contents of the dist folder on the server , instead of the dist folder totally and set the base href`<base href="./">`.

The dist folder will have the `index.html` plus all your dependencies like `assets` etc.

Comment: but i guess while build `<base href="/">` is default, anyways not working after changes. yes dist folder has everything

Comment: @PardeepJain ya that will be default i just mentioned it , where are you deploying it   ?

Comment: apche server i am using

Comment: @PardeepJain can you try and change the base ref path to the updated path i guess the error says it is not able to find the route structure and using this we can give a relative path

Comment: exactly man, i did already using setting manually path like `<base href="./">` and `<base href="/">` but not working

Comment: i copied dist folder totally as it is, is there any problem in that ?

Comment: @PardeepJain i guess you have a folder structure in you server like `parentFolder/childFolder/` can you try setting this a base path . i may be stupid on this but try once . No problem with the copying of dist . hope you did `ng build --prod` if youare using cli

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153200/discussion-between-pardeep-jain-and-rahul-singh).

Answer (score 0):

HI can can try **ng build --dev**,then do below apache configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.io
    ServerAlias test.io

    DocumentRoot your_project_path/angular2/dist
    <Directory your_project_path/angular2/dist>
            Require all granted

            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
            RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

            RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
    </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -1):

replace base tag with this script

```
<script>
    document.write('<base href="' +String(document.location).replace('index.html','') + '">')
</script>
```

Comment: you have to copy dist folder as it is in the server (webapps folder if its tomcat).This script will take care of the subdirectories you are creating inside. I am using tomcat and /parent/dist/index.html works fine.